# Following the 302 redirect after POST request in angularjs using $http

Tags: angularjs, http, http-status-code-302

Im sending a POST request using $http in angularjs, and server sends back the 200  response and doing a 302 redirect. I want to follow the 302 response and access the headers. is there a way to do this in angularjs? it would be nice if someone can help me on this with a sample code.

Comment: I'm confused, you say "server sends back the 200 response and doing a 302 redirect", what is that?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Are you using Spring Security (SS)? Check if SS permits the action that you are trying to access.